# Find the edges that cause Braess's paradox

Tags: algorithm, networkx, graph-theory, igraph, graph-tool

I have a graph (edges and nodes) and I would like to find the edges that cause Braess's paradox. Is there a way/algorithm to detect these edges?

Braess's paradox is the observation that adding one or more roads to a road network can slow down overall traffic flow through it.

In my case: I have a graph with sources at some nodes and loads at some other nodes. I want to identify edges that if removed, loads would still be able to get power from sources (through the rest of the edges)
Also, We should keep all sources and loads in the graph without these edges.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what Braess's paradox is, and what exact properties of the edges you're looking for? An example would help considerably, since the problem is about Nash equilibria in traffic flowing through a graph and not just the graph itself.

Comment: Thanks @kcsquared I updated the question to include more data

Comment: A simple solution comes to mind - check max throughput, then remove each edge and re-check; if throughput increases, then that edge is paradox-causing. Repeat with resulting graph, as there may be more than 1 such edge.

Comment: I'm still having some difficulty understanding the input data- do the edges have variable travel times? Could you give a small sample input and solution?

Comment: There are no weights for edges. All edges have the same wights.